# How can I mount a speaker on the ceiling?

Tags: mounting, home-theater, speakers

I want to [this heavy bookshelf speaker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0045NCB32) on my ceiling as a center-channel, preferably horizontally, as it's above my projection screen.  I want to angle it roughly 20 degrees downward so that it's properly aimed at a listener sitting on a couch about ten feet away.  It's 11 x 8.2 x 14.8 inches ; 16.1 pounds.

It has no bracket mounting holes, and I'd prefer not to screw into the cabinet, but will do so if necessary.  Wall mounted brackets are not going to work, because the screen is in front of a bay window.

[image]

Comment: There are swivel/tilt wall as well as ceiling mounts that can do what you want. Since your speakers don't have any mounting features you will need to screw into them

Comment: FYI if it has to go on the ceiling so be it, but ideally the center channel speaker would be mounted directly above or below the screen. Since the center speaker is used mainly for dialog it sounds more natural for it to be close to the image.

Comment: My screen is about a foot below the ceiling.

Comment: If it is at a bay window, add a shelf?

Comment: The bay window goes to the ceiling and is about three feet behind the screen, hence the need for ceiling mount. A shelf mounted to the ceiling is an option I'd thought of, if likely ugly and difficult to construct given the aiming angle.

Comment: If you are going into the ceiling, you really should be sure that the mounting brackets are attached to a piece of framing rather than drywall or plaster. A speaker is a somewhat dynamic load. It vibrates and you don't want it crashing down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needing to screw into the speaker cabinets is almost inevitable.  What should 
work is either a low-profile projector mount, such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B7KXBBC);

[image: Projector Mount]

Or alternately this [heavy duty wall mount](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005SEN20S), but mounted to the ceiling and long side of the speaker instead of the wall and back side of the speaker.

[image]

[This bracket](http://www.axiomaudio.com/full-metal-bracket#) would work similarly.

[image]

People were searching for solutions to the identical problem in this 2011 AVS Forum [thread](http://www.avsforum.com/forum/89-speakers/1377663-ceiling-mount-center-channel-speaker.html#/forumsite/3207/topics/1377663?page=1).

Answer (score 1):

Shelf is dead easy. Your basic shelf with a lip on the front edge so the speaker does not slide off, as beautiful as you like or as ugly as you don't is really up to you. Perhaps some felt to protect the speaker.

4 threaded rods or chains, 8 hooks (if using chains) 16 nuts and 8 washers if using threaded rod. Best option with threaded rod is to place a board in the attic above the framing and run the rods through the ceiling and through it (now you'll tell me you don't have an attic...) but lag screws with a machine screw threaded part are available, and can be screwed into the framing and have a barrel nut added to join to threaded rod.

The angle is achieved by making the back chains or rods shorter than the front ones. If you are willing to screw into the speaker, put 3-4 hooks on it and hang it with chains directly. Hooks for chains should go into framing.

Answer (score 0):

Use para-cord or wire rope or other strong cordage to create large loops with which to lasso and cradle the speaker unit. Using knots and/or small cable clamps you can configure the loops so that the speaker is oriented at the angle needed. Attach to ceiling hooks of appropriate type for the weight of the unit. I did exactly this in my early days bachelor pad.

Would be kinda like this pic:

[image]

Comment: You could use chain too, for a cool industrial look. Might damage the cabinet a bit though.

Comment: I'm looking for something a little more refined than rope, but it might work for some :)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=hanging+speaker+brackets&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMIpZn7-_P-yAIVGMBjCh1mWggE&biw=1164&bih=817#tbm=isch&tbs=rimg%3ACSr2fpFE1TNqIjiWftBigC461ds4_1kKU3Hw0INP-qydXyBrcYcDCW29gFJsvmeIrN2kW-I2jHnJRYtRab5f1izkXLSoSCZZ-0GKALjrVEYUbKbySwo91KhIJ2zj-QpTcfDQR6eIi-rBu4_1gqEgkg0_16rJ1fIGhHbHnhFljzW9CoSCdxhwMJbb2AUEX8OIxcmDnSDKhIJmy-Z4is3aRYRRyBN9jVCSMgqEgn4jaMeclFi1BFpr6sgCLdbdCoSCVpvl_1WLORctEbGyBJbzQn7d&q=hanging%20speaker%20brackets

Comment: Your imagination is your only limit: https://www.google.com/search?q=hanging+speaker+brackets&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMIpZn7-_P-yAIVGMBjCh1mWggE&biw=1164&bih=817#tbm=isch&tbs=rimg%3ACSr2fpFE1TNqIjiWftBigC461ds4_1kKU3Hw0INP-qydXyBrcYcDCW29gFJsvmeIrN2kW-I2jHnJRYtRab5f1izkXLSoSCZZ-0GKALjrVEYUbKbySwo91KhIJ2zj-QpTcfDQR6eIi-rBu4_1gqEgkg0_16rJ1fIGhHbHnhFljzW9CoSCdxhwMJbb2AUEX8OIxcmDnSDKhIJmy-Z4is3aRYRRyBN9jVCSMgqEgn4jaMeclFi1BFpr6sgCLdbdCoSCVpvl_1WLORctEbGyBJbzQn7d&q=hanging%20speaker%20brackets

Comment: Yes, I've Googled extensively.

Comment: Rope can degrade over time due to exposure to sunlight and pollutants in the air, I wouldn't suspend a 16 lb speaker using any type of rope. I'd stick with welded link chain or metal cable

Comment: @Johnny, yes rope can degrade (like all other materials) but even very small diameter synthetic fiber rope is more than capable of suspending that load safely for years and years and years.

Comment: Heh - I have hung a speaker of similar size for years in a hanger made from 3 lengths of *string*, doubled over and knotted (like a plant hanger- in fact, I've hung much heavier plants in hangers made the same way.) Far thinner than paracord.

Answer (score 0):

What is the distance between the walls located on the sides of your screen? You can try to do something similar shown in the drawing below. You do not need to make new holes on the speakers. As I see from the picture you provided above, there are screws that hold the case. So, replace them with the longer ones if it is necessary and use those points for mounting the speaker.

The red lines represent ropes, wires etc.
Using lightweight chain will make the mounting of speakers very easy. You just have to put the screws through one of the chain and screw it to the case.

[image]

Anyway, I do not recommend hanging or even putting speakers on a desk or something. I found out that they give the best sound when they are on the ground.

Good Luck